# Long press drops 2 pins with each tap

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer

I got my app dropping pin by long tap, i allow users to drop only two pins and its working i guess.. but every time i tap to add a pin in the simulator it adds two pins (not only one).. here is the code:

```
-(void) handleLongPressGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    if (pinId < 3) {
        // Here we get the CGPoint for the touch and convert it to
        // latitude and longitude coordinates to display on the map

        CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.mapView];       
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [self.mapView convertPoint:point
                                            toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];

        if (pinId == 1) {
            lat1 = coord.latitude;
            long1 = coord.longitude;

            MapAppAnnotation* annotation;
            annotation = [[MapAppAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord
                                                andID:pinId];

            [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

            MKCircle* circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:coord
                                        radius:5000];
            [mapView addOverlay:circle];    
            pinId++;

        } else {
            lat2 = coord.latitude;
            long2 = coord.longitude;
            MapAppAnnotation* annotation2;
            annotation2 = [[MapAppAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord
                                                andID:pinId];

            [mapView addAnnotation:annotation2];
        }
    } 
}
```

I would like to know if is my fault (code error..) or is the iPhone simulator that get my long-mouse-pressure like two different long pressures.. is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector is being called once when the gesture begins, and again when it ends. Check the gesture's state and act on the relevant one.

```
-(void)handleLongPressGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    if (sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) return;

    // otherwise, handle the gesture as before
}
```

The class reference for [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says:

> Long-press gestures are continuous.
>   The gesture begins
>   (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) when
>   the number of allowable fingers
>   (numberOfTouchesRequired) have been
>   pressed for the specified period
>   (minimumPressDuration) and the touches
>   do not move beyond the allowable range
>   of movement (allowableMovement). The
>   gesture recognizer transitions to the
>   Change state whenever a finger moves,
>   and it ends
>   (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) when
>   any of the fingers are lifted.